# KeyError in module 'threading' after a successful py.test run

Tags: python, gevent, pytest

I'm running a set of tests with py.test. They pass. Yippie! But I'm getting this message:

```
Exception KeyError: KeyError(4427427920,) in <module 'threading' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

How should I go about tracking down the source of that? (I'm not using threading directly, but am using gevent.)

Answer (score 221, accepted):

I observed a similar issue and decided to see what's going on exactly - let me describe my findings. I hope someone will find it useful.

### Short story

It is indeed related to monkey-patching the `threading` module. In fact, I can easily trigger the exception by importing the threading module before monkey-patching threads. The following 2 lines are enough:

```
import threading
import gevent.monkey; gevent.monkey.patch_thread()
```

When executed it spits the message about ignored `KeyError`:

```
(env)czajnik@autosan:~$ python test.py 
Exception KeyError: KeyError(139924387112272,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

If you swap the import lines, the problem is gone.

### Long story

I could stop my debugging here, but I decided it's worth to understand the exact cause of the problem.

First step was to find the code that prints the message about ignored exception. It was a little hard for me to find it (grepping for `Exception.*ignored` yielded nothing), but grepping around CPython source code I've eventually found a function called `void PyErr_WriteUnraisable(PyObject *obj)` in [Python/error.c](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/tags/r27/Python/errors.c), with a very interesting comment:

```
/* Call when an exception has occurred but there is no way for Python
   to handle it.  Examples: exception in __del__ or during GC. */
```

I decided to check who's calling it, with a little help from `gdb`, just to get the following C-level stack trace:

```
#0  0x0000000000542c40 in PyErr_WriteUnraisable ()
#1  0x00000000004af2d3 in Py_Finalize ()
#2  0x00000000004aa72e in Py_Main ()
#3  0x00007ffff68e576d in __libc_start_main (main=0x41b980 <main>, argc=2,
    ubp_av=0x7fffffffe5f8, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, 
    rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffe5e8) at libc-start.c:226
#4  0x000000000041b9b1 in _start ()
```

Now we can clearly see that the exception is thrown while [Py_Finalize](http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#Py_Finalize) executes - this call is responsible for shutting down the Python interpreter, freeing allocated memory, etc. It's called just before exitting.

Next step was to look at `Py_Finalize()` code (it's in [Python/pythonrun.c](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/tags/r27/Python/pythonrun.c)). The very first call it makes is `wait_for_thread_shutdown()` - worth looking at, as we know the problem is related to threading. This function in turn calls `_shutdown` callable in the `threading` module. Good, we can go back to python code now.

Looking at `threading.py` I've found the following interesting parts:

```
class _MainThread(Thread):

    def _exitfunc(self):
        self._Thread__stop()
        t = _pickSomeNonDaemonThread()
        if t:
            if __debug__:
                self._note("%s: waiting for other threads", self)
        while t:
            t.join()
            t = _pickSomeNonDaemonThread()
        if __debug__:
            self._note("%s: exiting", self)
        self._Thread__delete()

# Create the main thread object,
# and make it available for the interpreter
# (Py_Main) as threading._shutdown.

_shutdown = _MainThread()._exitfunc
```

Clearly, the responsibility of `threading._shutdown()` call is to join all non-daemon threads and delete main thread (whatever that means exactly). I decided to patch `threading.py` a bit - wrap the whole `_exitfunc()` body with `try`/`except` and print the stack trace with [traceback](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html) module. This gave the following trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 785, in _exitfunc
    self._Thread__delete()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 639, in __delete
    del _active[_get_ident()]
KeyError: 26805584
```

Now we know the exact place where the exception is thrown - inside `Thread.__delete()` method.

The rest of the story is obvious after reading `threading.py` for a while. The `_active` dictionary maps thread IDs (as returned by `_get_ident()`) to `Thread` instances, for all threads created. When `threading` module is loaded, an instance of `_MainThread` class is always created and added to `_active` (even if no other threads are explicitly created).

The problem is that one of the methods patched by `gevent`'s monkey-patching is `_get_ident()` - original one maps to `thread.get_ident()`, monkey-patching replaces it with `green_thread.get_ident()`. Obviously both calls return different IDs for main thread.

Now, if `threading` module is loaded before monkey-patching, `_get_ident()` call returns one value when `_MainThread` instance is created and added to `_active`, and another value at the time `_exitfunc()` is called - hence `KeyError` in `del _active[_get_ident()]`.

On the contrary, if monkey-patching is done before `threading` is loaded, all is fine - at the time `_MainThread` instance is being added to `_active`, `_get_ident()` is already patched, and the same thread ID is returned at cleanup time. That's it!

To make sure I import modules in the right order, I added the following snippet to my code, just before monkey-patching call:

```
import sys
if 'threading' in sys.modules:
        raise Exception('threading module loaded before patching!')
import gevent.monkey; gevent.monkey.patch_thread()
```

I hope you find my debugging story useful :)

Comment: Great answer, but TLDR; your imports are in the wrong order, make sure your very first imports are `import gevent.monkey; gevent.monkey.patch_all()` then whatever else you want to import

Comment: That's exactly what I state above - import order is important.

Answer (score 19):

You could use this:

```
import sys
if 'threading' in sys.modules:
    del sys.modules['threading']
import gevent
import gevent.socket
import gevent.monkey
gevent.monkey.patch_all()
```

Comment: I like this silent approach. But remember to have a `import sys` above the snippet :)

Comment: I had wanted to do something like this to try to load gevent later. Things like http://justus.science/blog/2015/04/19/sys.modules-is-dangerous.html

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a gevent prototype script.

The Greenlet callback was executing fine and I was synchronizing back to the main thread via g.join(). For my problem, I had to call gevent.shutdown() to shutdown (what I assume is) the Hub. After I manually shutdown the event loop, the program terminates properly without that error.

Comment: +1 -- but I'm asking about how to track down the source of the issue, not how to pave over the issue.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing with `gevent` while running tests with `nose`. Oddly enough, when the tests all pass I don't see the error, but when a test fails I see it. I'm using `monkey.patch_all()`. Notably, when I do `monkey.patch_all(thread=False)` the errors go away.

Comment: Tracking down the error could be fairly difficult. If I'm understanding this problem, it has to do with the background thread that is running. It seems like the problem is coming from the main loop terminating before the background thread has the ability to finish what it's doing. The interrupt from the main thread terminating must be causing the program to throw the exception. I think the best way to solve this problem is to make sure all threads have finished processing before shutting down the main process.

Comment: @Kris I agree both about the difficutly and what's likely causing the issue. What's not clear to me what's firing off threads, what the threads are doing, and why they're not properly finishing. I guess I'll just assume that it's something in gevent, that everything I'm doing is fine, and that gevent.shutdown() will just do the right thing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Daniel: you may want to see my post: http://blog.codepainters.com/2012/11/20/gevent-monkey-patching-versus-sniffer-nose/