# thread exception occurred in gevent when using python

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, gevent

When I run this python code, but some thread problem occurred. I search the internet,but I don't find the answer.

```
import urllib2
from time import time
import gevent
import numpy as np

tmp = np.loadtxt('data.txt', dtype=str)
visit_list=tmp[:20]

result_list =[]

def visitUrl(u):
  print 'start %s' %u
  begin = time()
  data = urllib2.urlopen(u).read()
  print len(data)
  print 'end-------- %s' %u
  end = time()
  print ('%s ::begin=%s ::end= %s::end-begin= %s' %(u, begin,end, end-begin))

for i in range(3):
    reqs = []
    begin = time()
    for u in visit_list:
        start = time()
        reqs.append(gevent.spawn(visitUrl, u))
        stop = time()
        print ('%s $$$ %s' %(u, stop-start))
    #reqs = [gevent.spawn(visitUrl, u) for u in visit_list]
    gevent.joinall(reqs)
    end = time()

    print 'ciclie %s=%s' %(i, end - begin)
    result_list.append(end-begin)
```

the problem:

```
Exception KeyError: KeyError(4475468392,) in <module 'threading' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

Comment: I ran your code and it works fine. Which OS does you have? Which version of python and gevent? Which urls are in data.txt?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774958/keyerror-in-module-threading-after-a-successful-py-test-run) your main loop ends before all threads have done its job.

Just call `gevent.shutdown()` at the end or increase timeout while calling `joinall`:

```
gevent.joinall(reqs, timeout=30)
```

Comment: You're welcome. If I solved your problem, consider clicking checkmark for this answer, to compensate a little bit for my effor. ;-)