# Number of active threads

Tags: python, multithreading

Python version: '2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:20:15) \n[GCC 4.6.3]'

I have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time, threading, os
def f1(arg1):
    for i in xrange(arg1):
        time.sleep(1)
        print "i is: ", i
        print threading.active_count()
        print threading.enumerate()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    t = threading.Thread(name="MyThread1", target=f1, args=(5,))
    t.start()
```

My question is, why is the number of active threads being reported as 2 and why does the list generated by `enumerate` contain the main thread as well.

I was thinking that the main thread terminates after spawning "MyThread1".

$ ./threadeg.py

```
i is:  0
2
[<_MainThread(MainThread, stopped 139858183157504)>, <Thread(MyThread1, started 139858153768704)>]

i is:  1
2
[<_MainThread(MainThread, stopped 139858183157504)>, <Thread(MyThread1, started 139858153768704)>]

i is:  2
2
[<_MainThread(MainThread, stopped 139858183157504)>, <Thread(MyThread1, started 139858153768704)>]

i is:  3
2
[<_MainThread(MainThread, stopped 139858183157504)>, <Thread(MyThread1, started 139858153768704)>]

i is:  4
2
[<_MainThread(MainThread, stopped 139858183157504)>, <Thread(MyThread1, started 139858153768704)>]
```

Comment: The main thread doesn't terminate while other non-daemon threads exist.

Comment: @Cairnarvon What is the source of your reference based on which you are making the statement? Can I please know?

Answer (score 1):

> threading.activeCount() which returns the number of threads active
>   (that were started with that module). [[Source]](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2002-May/173585.html)

Since the threading module is a pure python module built on top of the thread module, it's pretty easy to view the source code.

Here is the source code for `active_count`

```
def activeCount():
    """Return the number of Thread objects currently alive.

    The returned count is equal to the length of the list returned by
    enumerate().

    """
    with _active_limbo_lock:
        return len(_active) + len(_limbo)
```

upon further investigation it should be noted that there is a _MainThread instance is stored in _active (_active and _limbo are both dictionaries that map thread names to their instances). And is deleted from _active when `_exitfunc` is called.

Here is the source for _MainThread,

```
class _MainThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self, name="MainThread")
        self._Thread__started.set()
        self._set_ident()
        with _active_limbo_lock:
            _active[_get_ident()] = self

    def _set_daemon(self):
        return False

    def _exitfunc(self):
        self._Thread__stop()
        t = _pickSomeNonDaemonThread()
        if t:
            if __debug__:
                self._note("%s: waiting for other threads", self)
        while t:
            t.join()
            t = _pickSomeNonDaemonThread()
        if __debug__:
            self._note("%s: exiting", self)
        self._Thread__delete()
```

once `_exitfunc` is called `_MainThread` waits for all non daemon threads to join and then calls `Thread._delete` which in this case has been [mangled](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) to `__Thread_delete` which in turn removes `_MainThread` from the `_active` dictionary.

`_exitfunc` is assigned to `_shutdown` on line 1201.

```
_shutdown = _MainThread()._exitfunc
```

`_shutdown` is called from [pythonrun.c](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.6/file/4913d0e9be30/Python/pythonrun.c#l1703), which in turn is called by [`Py_Finalize`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#Py_Finalize). `Py_Finalize` is called by [Py_Exit](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.6/file/4913d0e9be30/Python/pythonrun.c#l1775), which exits the main process (at this point only daemons are left).

[Py_Exit's documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/sys.html#Py_Exit).

> Exit the current process. This calls Py_Finalize() and then calls the standard C library function exit(status).

Here is an example to get you the behavior you expect.

```
import threading, time

def f():
    time.sleep(1) #wait for the interpreter to "shutdown"
    print threading.enumerate()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    t = threading.Thread(target=f)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

    threading._shutdown() #simulate an interpreter shutdown
```

Another great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12639040/322909) describing how threads are shutdown.